# progress after FadeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wan't to call the animate function when the fadeOut is complete. Not during it's fading out. I think that the "progress" function in fadeOut is the right. Can someone help me I don't know how to apply the "progress" function on my code.

```
$(".intro").animate({height:'100%', width:'100%'}, 2000, function(){
            $(this).append("<div class='text'>Welcome to Progressbar_v1</div>"); $(".text").css({"height":"23px","width":"auto","position":"absolute","top":"0","left":"0","bottom":"0","right":"0","margin":"auto"}).animate({fontSize:'3em'},"slow");
            $(".text").fadeOut(4000);
});
$(".intro").animate({height:'30px', width:'500px'}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.fadeOut()` callback

```
$(".intro").animate({height:'100%', width:'100%'}, 2000, function(){
            $(this).append("<div class='text'>Welcome to Progressbar_v1</div>"); $(".text").css({"height":"23px","width":"auto","position":"absolute","top":"0","left":"0","bottom":"0","right":"0","margin":"auto"}).animate({fontSize:'3em'},"slow");
            $(".text").fadeOut(4000, function() {
                 $(".intro").animate({height:'30px', width:'500px'}, 2000);
            });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter of fadeOut take a function which is executed when the animation is complete.

Place your code there and see the documentation for more information http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/

```
$(".intro").animate({height:'100%', width:'100%'}, 2000, function(){
  $(this).append("<div class='text'>Welcome to Progressbar_v1</div>"); $(".text").css({"height":"23px","width":"auto","position":"absolute","top":"0","left":"0","bottom":"0","right":"0","margin":"auto"}).animate({fontSize:'3em'},"slow");
  $(".text").fadeOut(4000, function() {
    $(".intro").animate({height:'30px', width:'500px'}, 2000);
  });
});
```